# Codeigniter database switch - Issue in session (DB session table) for switched database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, multiple-databases

I have multiple databases for my portal. One is master database and others are child databases. I am using codeigniter session using a database table.

Now when I open the portal, the master database is called. Based on the url it switches to any one of child databases. A first session entry is created in the master database and then it would switch to another database.

The issue is, when it is checking for session id to update userdata value, connected DB is now switched to child. So the entry is not found and userdata value is not being updated. How do I create a new entry in child DB and update userdata value?

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.1.3

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use database routing, this does means, you should remain connected to the main database, or make a special routed database for sessions. You could for one copy the data before you switch, I personally do not recommend this as it's not giving any advantages. What I would do is create a special database just for sessions in your case. You could have multiple connections in CI which will allow quick access to multiple databases.

Comment: @killstreet: Thanks for the comment. I applied the steps from following link:https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/ci-session-specific-database It is not working. I am using CI 2.1.3 and I think the solution is for CI 3.x Is there any other way for CI 2.x?

Comment: @NishitModi I'd recommend looking at https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html this link. It shows how to create multiple connections for databases and how to connect / close them when you use them.